# JLabel does not show value from another class

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have two GUI classes. When I click a row in `JTable` in the first user interface, the second interface should display the corresponding values in `JLabels`.
But the second user interface does not show the values.

Here's my first GUI class:

```
public class ChequeGUI extends JFrame {

public String chqNo;
public String payName;
public double chkAmount = 10;
public Date chkDate;

JTable guiTable = new JTable();

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new String[]{"Cheque Number","Payee Name","Cheque Amount","Cheque Date"});

public ChequeGUI() throws SQLException {

    guiTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

            //guiTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

            int row = guiTable.getSelectedRow();

            chqNo = (String) guiTable.getValueAt(row,0);
            payName = (String) guiTable.getValueAt(row,1);
            chkAmount = (Double) guiTable.getValueAt(row,2);
            chkDate = (Date) guiTable.getValueAt(row, 3);

            try {
                PrintChequeGUI pcg = new PrintChequeGUI();
                pcg.setTitle("Print Cheque");
                pcg.setVisible(true);

                System.out.println(chqNo);
                System.out.println(payName);
                System.out.println(chkAmount);
                System.out.println(chkDate);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    guiTable.setModel(model);
    add(new JScrollPane(guiTable));

    DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();

    //Populate Table
    ChequeDAOImpl chqdi = new ChequeDAOImpl();
    chqdi.setConnection(connection);
    List<Cheque> cheques = chqdi.getCheques();


    for(Cheque cq : cheques){
    model.addRow(new Object[]{cq.getChqNum(), cq.getName(),cq.getAmount(),cq.getDate()});
    }

}



 }
```

This is my second GUI class:

```
public class PrintChequeGUI extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtAmount;

/**
 * Create the frame.
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public PrintChequeGUI() throws SQLException {

    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 480, 400);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(176, 224, 230));
    contentPane.setForeground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 11, 454, 84);
    contentPane.add(panel);


    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 220));
    panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
    panel_1.setBounds(10, 106, 454, 198);
    contentPane.add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Date:");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(327, 11, 40, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel lblDate = new JLabel();
    lblDate.setBounds(368, 11, 69, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblDate);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Payee to the Order of");
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(10, 50, 125, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_2);

    JLabel lblName = new JLabel();
    lblName.setBounds(134, 50, 214, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblName);

    JLabel lblRs = new JLabel("Rs.");
    lblRs.setBounds(351, 50, 24, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblRs);

    JLabel lblAmount = new JLabel();
    lblAmount.setBounds(375, 50, 69, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblAmount);

    txtAmount = new JTextField();
    txtAmount.setBounds(10, 83, 338, 20);
    panel_1.add(txtAmount);
    txtAmount.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblRupees = new JLabel("Rupees");
    lblRupees.setBounds(351, 86, 46, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblRupees);

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Cheque Number:");
    lbl.setBounds(10, 126, 100, 14);
    panel_1.add(lbl);

    JLabel lblChequeNum = new JLabel();
    lblChequeNum.setBounds(115, 126, 46, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblChequeNum);

    JLabel lblSig = new JLabel("<<Sig>>");
    lblSig.setBounds(321, 151, 90, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblSig);

    JLabel lblSigName = new JLabel("A.B.C.Test Name");
    lblSigName.setBounds(311, 176, 100, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblSigName);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 220));
    panel_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
    panel_2.setBounds(10, 315, 454, 40);
    contentPane.add(panel_2);
    panel_2.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnPrint = new JButton("Print");
    btnPrint.setBounds(102, 11, 89, 23);
    panel_2.add(btnPrint);

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
    btnBack.setBounds(263, 11, 89, 23);
    panel_2.add(btnBack);

    ChequeGUI gui = new ChequeGUI();
    lblChequeNum.setText(gui.chqNo);
    lblAmount.setText(Double.toString(gui.chkAmount));
    lblName.setText(gui.payName);
    lblDate.setText(String.valueOf(gui.chkDate));

}
}
```

Comment: Try `resizing` your frame on run time. I think is not `repainting` itself after populating labels from `ChequeGUI`

Comment: I tried resizing. But it is not working.

Comment: The instance of ChequeGUI you are using in PrintChequeGUI is new and the details from the previous will not get in second dialog. Please pass the current instance of ChequeGUI using `this` to PrintChequeGUI and use that instance instead of new one

Comment: This may be a foolish question. But could you tell me how to use the current instance? Because I don't understand how to do it without creating a new object.

Comment: i already mensioned that using this keyword

Comment: I used this keyword. But it does not show the variables when I put the dot.

Comment: It is because you are calling this from inside of `MouseAdapter` class. By calling this from `MouseAdapter` you'll get current instance of `MouseAdapter` class. Please use `ChequeGUI.this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved in many ways:

## 1.

As I mentioned in my comment, Pass the current instance of `ChequeGUI` to the constructor of `PrintChequeGUI` and use that instance instead of creating new one in `PrintChequeGUI`

`PrintChequeGUI pcg = new PrintChequeGUI(this);`

and in `PrintChequeGUI` class

`public PrintChequeGUI(ChequeGUI gui) throws SQLException {`

(but i think its not a good approach)

## 2.

For Better option, Pass the selected instance of `Cheque` to `PrintChequeGUI` as constructor argument.   For this you need to create a `TableModel` with instance of `Cheque`.
Sample is given below:

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class ChequeGUI extends JFrame {

JTable guiTable = new JTable();

ChequeTableModel model;

public ChequeGUI() throws SQLException {

    guiTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            // guiTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

            int row = guiTable.getSelectedRow();

            Cheque c = model.getChequeByRow(row);

            try {
                PrintChequeGUI pcg = new PrintChequeGUI(c);
                pcg.setTitle("Print Cheque");
                pcg.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    model = new ChequeTableModel();
    guiTable.setModel(model);
    add(new JScrollPane(guiTable));

    model.loadData();

}

public class ChequeTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    List<Cheque> dataModel;

    String[] columns = { "Cheque Number", "Payee Name", "Cheque Amount",
            "Cheque Date" };

    public ChequeTableModel() {
        super();
        dataModel = new ArrayList<Cheque>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columns[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataModel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        Object value = null;

        Cheque c = getChequeByRow(row);
        switch (column) {
        case 0:
            value = c.chqNo;
            break;
        case 1:
            value = c.payName;
            break;
        case 2:
            value = c.chkAmount;
            break;
        case 3:
            value = c.chkDate;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public Cheque getChequeByRow(int row) {
        if (dataModel.size() <= 0)
            return null;
        if (row < 0)
            return null;

        return dataModel.get(row);
    }

    public void loadData() {
        /*
         * 
         * //Uncomment this for database connection and load data from
         * database; //Please note to disconnect database if not needed
         * 
         * 
         * DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
         * 
         * // Populate Table ChequeDAOImpl chqdi = new ChequeDAOImpl();
         * chqdi.setConnection(connection); List<Cheque> cheques =
         * chqdi.getCheques();
         * 
         * for (Cheque cq : cheques) { model.addRow(new Object[] {
         * cq.getChqNum(), cq.getName(), cq.getAmount(), cq.getDate() }); }
         */

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Cheque c = new Cheque();
            c.chkAmount = i * 1000;
            c.chqNo = String.valueOf(i);
            c.chkDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            dataModel.add(c);
        }
        fireTableRowsInserted(0, dataModel.size());
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    ChequeGUI c = new ChequeGUI();
    c.pack();
    c.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Second class

```
package com.test;

 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.SystemColor;
 import java.sql.SQLException;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class PrintChequeGUI extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtAmount;

/**
 * Create the frame.
 * 
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public PrintChequeGUI(Cheque cheque) throws SQLException {

    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 480, 400);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(176, 224, 230));
    contentPane.setForeground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 11, 454, 84);
    contentPane.add(panel);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 220));
    panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
    panel_1.setBounds(10, 106, 454, 198);
    contentPane.add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Date:");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(327, 11, 40, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel lblDate = new JLabel();
    lblDate.setBounds(368, 11, 69, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblDate);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Payee to the Order of");
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(10, 50, 125, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_2);

    JLabel lblName = new JLabel();
    lblName.setBounds(134, 50, 214, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblName);

    JLabel lblRs = new JLabel("Rs.");
    lblRs.setBounds(351, 50, 24, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblRs);

    JLabel lblAmount = new JLabel();
    lblAmount.setBounds(375, 50, 69, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblAmount);

    txtAmount = new JTextField();
    txtAmount.setBounds(10, 83, 338, 20);
    panel_1.add(txtAmount);
    txtAmount.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblRupees = new JLabel("Rupees");
    lblRupees.setBounds(351, 86, 46, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblRupees);

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Cheque Number:");
    lbl.setBounds(10, 126, 100, 14);
    panel_1.add(lbl);

    JLabel lblChequeNum = new JLabel();
    lblChequeNum.setBounds(115, 126, 46, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblChequeNum);

    JLabel lblSig = new JLabel("<<Sig>>");
    lblSig.setBounds(321, 151, 90, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblSig);

    JLabel lblSigName = new JLabel("A.B.C.Test Name");
    lblSigName.setBounds(311, 176, 100, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblSigName);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 220));
    panel_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
    panel_2.setBounds(10, 315, 454, 40);
    contentPane.add(panel_2);
    panel_2.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnPrint = new JButton("Print");
    btnPrint.setBounds(102, 11, 89, 23);
    panel_2.add(btnPrint);

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
    btnBack.setBounds(263, 11, 89, 23);
    panel_2.add(btnBack);

    // ChequeGUI gui = new ChequeGUI();
    lblChequeNum.setText(cheque.chqNo);
    lblAmount.setText(Double.toString(cheque.chkAmount));
    lblName.setText(cheque.payName);
    lblDate.setText(String.valueOf(cheque.chkDate));

}
}
```

The `Cheque` class you already used to get details from database

Comment: Please accept if it worked. Better use any of [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead of `null`. It'll help you to align controls automatically. And try to use `JDialog` for the second frame which open from first one. It'll helpful to maintain frame heirarchy

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying using your code now. Thanks for the suggestions. They are helpful.